# Bootstrap 3 not handling inline elements correctly on page resize

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I've run into some trouble with Bootstrap 3.2.0. Basically, I have a header menu with some *li* elements and inline with that I have a simple login form.

Please see my code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/beftqft5/)

the problem is that the css in not correctly handling the left and right floated elements

Weirdly enough, everything seems to work when only a single input element is present, as you can see [here](http://jsfiddle.net/967k4a8j/)

Please note that the html is taken directly from Bootstrap examples at

```
- http://getbootstrap.com/examples/jumbotron/
- http://getbootstrap.com/examples/dashboard/
```

p.s. the Jumbotron seems to work just fine with the login form but I'm guessing that is because there is no ul/li left floating menu

I'd appreciate any help you can offer

Thank you

**Edit**

Hey guys and thank you for replies so far. I'm not sure whether this is the expected behaviour

-> [image: http://i.imgur.com/XqYuTN1.png]

i.e. the login form is pushed to the next row, but I would expect it to collapse everything into a "mobile" type of menu before pushing the form down onto the next row.

**Edit 2**

p.s. the screenshot above is from Firefox 31.0 (and I see the same Chrome Version 36.0.1985.125 m)

Comment: looks fine for me, what are you expecting it to do?

Comment: Perhaps you're encountering https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=377346 ?

Comment: It is working normally. I think you mean that when you resize it, the form is shifting below the other items. This is normal because there are too many items for that width. You can go to the customizer on GetBootstrap.com and choose the 992 break point for your mobile menu to kick in, rather than the 768px default.

Comment: @BootstrapThemer thanks for your reply, but how would I do that for a dynamic menu where I do not know the width (or the number of items) in the menu on the left side? I thought that entire point (using something like bootstrap) was that it would be handled automatically.

Comment: @cvrebert hmmm not sure I follow the bug exactly, but I see the same problem in Firefox (please see my Edit above)

Comment: There is no framework that allows for unknown elements and then adjusts accordingly so that nothing gets pushed down, you can probably do something with jQuery.

Comment: @BootstrapThemer hey, thank you again for the reply. So, while the frameworks allow me to change the view based on viewport size, they cannot allow me to change the view based on the size of the element (at least no with pure ccs). That actually makes sense. Could you please point me in the right direction of what css I'd need to set the jQuery? I'm assuming I'd need to get the size of the two floated elements in the menu and set the breaking point based on that value? Thank you

Comment: @scibuff See the "Overflowing content" box on http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few ways you can handle this...

1) Customize the Bootstrap CSS so the menu collapses at a different screen size: i.e. at http://getbootstrap.com/customizer, change `@grid-float-breakpoint` to = `@screen-md-min`.

2) Add some of your own custom CSS to shrink the input fields to ~ `width:100px` at the right time, via a custom class added to the input-group, and a media query:

```
@media(min-width:768px) and (max-width:992px){
  .custom-class{width:100px;} /* tweak this px-count to get exactly what you want */
}
```

3) Using Bootstrap's hidden/visible column classes, put the login elements within a `popover` for only the `sm` screen size. This is the "Advanced" option, and is probably overkill, but fun to try. It would be something like:

```
...
<div class="visible-sm">
  <div class="popover" html="true">Put your inputs, button and other HTML here</div>
</div>
<div class="hidden-sm">
  <input ... ><!-- Put your regular login here -->
```

Comment: Thank you, this looks promising, I'm just not sure how I'd go about making this work for a dynamic menu. You see, I do not know the number of items which will be displayed in the left float, it can be anything (based on what a user sets via a CMS). So, how can setting a fixed breaking point handle this.

Honestly, I kind of expected bootstrap to handle the resizing correctly out of the box ...

Comment: Hey, so 1) works nicely but I'd like to use the default css from a cdn (which I cannot change) and it doesn't seem to be possible to override the breaking point with compiled css (at least I cant get it to work)
2) works nicely too

if no one else posts anything "more useful" I'll set yours as the accepted answer.